# Cytoscape 3.0 Bundle App

Tags: cytoscape

I'm trying to create a new Cytoscape 3.x application following the [Create a Bundle App Using IDE](http://opentutorials.cgl.ucsf.edu/index.php/Tutorial%3aCreate_a_Bundle_App_Using_IDE) tutorial with no luck.

The tutorial is quite easy to follow, however when I run Cytoscape to find out if my app is running, I can see that it is listed as *Installed* but it is not *Active*.

I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent an email to Cytoscape 3 developers and apparently, there is something wrong in the Archtype. It can be solved by changing the cytoscape dependencies version to **[3.0.0,3.0.9)** in the pom.xml file.